# Absolute Positioned Iframe is covering fixed footer

Tags: iframe, youtube

Here is what I am trying to accomplish.  I have background that I want to put an iframe element on top of.

the html i used is as follows:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="images/videoframe.png" id="img1" />
    <iframe id="img2" width="370" height="209" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/BWW7te-P5Ak?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

the css i used to accomplish this is as follows:

```
#container {
    position:relative;
}

#img2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 29px;
```

I managed to get it to work perfectly.  My problem is this...
I have a fixed footer and the iframe (but only the iframe) is overlapping and covering part of the fixed footer.

My html for the fixed footer is as follows:

```
<div class="floatingfooter">
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com/TraumaSlaveSC" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('FacebookIcon','','images/socialmedia/Stone-FaceBook2.png',1)"><img src="images/socialmedia/Stone-FaceBook.png" alt="Like Us on Facebook" name="FacebookIcon" width="86" height="85" border="0" class="centerimage" id="FacebookIcon" /></a>

<a href="http://www.facebook.com/TraumaSlaveSC" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('MySpaceIcon','','images/socialmedia/Stone-MySpace2.png',0)"><img src="images/socialmedia/Stone-MySpace.png" alt="Add Us on MySpace" name="MySpaceIcon" width="85" height="85" border="0" class="centerimage" id="MySpaceIcon" /></a> 



<a href="http://www.reverbnation.com/traumaslave" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('ReverbNationIcon','','images/socialmedia/Stone-Reverb2.png',1)"><img src="images/socialmedia/Stone-Reverb.png" alt="Listen to us on Reverbnation" name="ReverbNationIcon" width="85" height="85" border="0" class="centerimage" id="ReverbNationIcon" /></a> 
<a href="http://twitter.com/traumaslavefan" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('TwitterIcon','','images/socialmedia/Stone-Twitter2.png',1)"><img src="images/socialmedia/Stone-Twitter.png" alt="Follow Us on Twitter" name="TwitterIcon" width="86" height="85" border="0" class="centerimage" id="TwitterIcon" /></a><a href="http://www.youtube.com/traumaslave" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('YouTubeIcon','','images/socialmedia/Stone-YouTube2.png',1)"><img src="images/socialmedia/Stone-YouTube.png" alt="Watch Our YouTube Channel" name="YouTubeIcon" width="85" height="85" border="0" class="centerimage" id="YouTubeIcon" /></a></div>
```

My CSS for the fixed footer is here:

```
.floatingfooter {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #7A6D50;
    text-align: center;
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 105px;
    z-index: 100000;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

The website where the code is currently posted is www.traumaslave.com

This has really got me stumped.

I am in the early design phases so I understand my coding is realllly rough.  I need to clean it up.  however, I would like to know

how to make the iframe scroll under the fixed footer

OR

if anyone has any better ideas for putting the iframe in a neat background that will circumvent this issue

OR

if the problem is the iframe itself, if anyone knows a solution for embedding a youtube video that will not include iframes and will still allow coding for embedding the video on a background.

Thanks so much!

Jennifer

Comment: also i tried ?wmode=transparent and z index.  nothing is working.

Comment: I can't believe i still have no replies.  :(  This is disappointing.  Well, I guess i'll try for another solution independently.  like maybe find some js that will run the video.  I dunno.  ......

Comment: Almost 10 years later came across the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up changing the static footer to be a static sidebar.  It ended up looking better, and I don't need to worry about overlapping elements.  I am still so very disappointed that I never received a response. :(  So if anyone out there is having this same issue and looking up this post, I advise that you try a sidebar.  It worked good for me because my navigation pane is horizontal so it doesn't look quirky.

Happy coding!

Jenn